# how to run requirement.txt file using pip?

Tags: python, pip

I try to run an python project. So I created python virtual environment

```
sudo python3 -m venv env
```

After this I activate environment

```
source env/bin/activate
```

after this I try to install requirement from requirement.txt file using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but It show an error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/selenium/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/async_generator-1.10.dist-info'
```

Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: You created the virtual environment as root, so now only root has write permissions to it. Don't use root; it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create the environment with `sudo` since it will be owned by root. You don't need `sudo` because you should create the environment in a place you have access to. Preferably somewhere in your user/home directory (depending on OS).